# How should I list my consulting gigs on careers?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Currently I am working for software consulting company X. They pay me a salary. While working for X, they have sent me to companies A, B, C, D and E. I have done very different things at each of those companies and some of them are big name banks. Some have been year long engagements while some have been as short as a month.

How should I list my experience on careers? Should I have Experience entries for each A, B, C, D and E  Or should I try and fit all of the work I have done for companies A, B, C, D and E under my entry for company X?

Separate Entries

- Pro: Name dropping of big companies
- Pro: Work that I have done can be highlighted better
- Con: Really long experience list with some really short term engagements

One Big Entry

- Pro: A lot of experience from one company
- Pro: Doesn't look like I job hop
- Con: Difficult to list out a lot of responsibilities in a nice way

Comment: what should the sister site be for programming job/work/interview related questions be? - I don't think its meta, but I'm not sure if there is one yet for this area.

Comment: @scunlife - it seems that meta catches all the discussions over the quintilogy.. it's certainly a convenient location :)

Comment: that being said.. a "discussion" aspect to c.so *might* be a better solution

Comment: I would go and list some of the longer consults on their own, and add the rest to the consulting company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the clients ***allow*** you to reference them you should, with whatever information they've allowed you to share (perhaps via a recommendation on LinkedIn).

If they do ***NOT*** allow you to share that, then you have to leave it out - or risk them suing you for breach of your NDA.

I *think* I have the legalities right, which vary by jurisdiction, and I'm not a lawyer :)

---

And of the two formats, I'd choose the second, because that's how my resume and LinkedIn profile is setup :)